# How to use prop variables inside vue formulate?

Tags: javascript, vue-props, vue-formulate

I was trying to pass data to a child component using v-bind for my vue formulate form input. I passed data like this in parent.

```
<ChildForm v-bind:formData="formData" ></ChildForm>

    export default {
      name: "Parent",
      data() {
        return {

    formData: {
          Full_Name: "",
          Notes: "",
          Address: "",
          Phone: "",
          City: "",
          State: "",
          Zip: "",
    },
    }}}
```

And in Child, I'm doing this

```
    <FormulateForm v-model="formData">
      <FormulateInput
                type="textarea"
                name="Notes"
                label="NOTES"
                validation="required|max:200,length"
                validation-name="Notes"
                :help="`Keep it under 200 characters. ${200 - this.formData.Notes.length} left.`"
              />

      <FormulateInput
               type="submit"
               label="Submit Details"
               />
    </FormulateForm>

export default {
  name: "ChildForm",
  props: {
    formData: Object,
  },
}
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
formData.Notes.length
```

instead of

```
this.formData.Notes.length
```

Comment: Do you set string value as formData.Notes? And 'patientForm' name is invalid. 'child-form' is correct.

Comment: oh..yea..that was a copy paste error when i typed in here my question. I have edited and made child-form now. I didn't really get the question regarding string value of formData.Notes...